# Extract element by xpath when the order of the elements are changing( Even the relative xpath is changing)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract text from a webpage with the Xpath as belows

```
//*[@id="twocols"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]
```

using the python code

```
updatetime=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="twocols"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]').text
```

which is ultimately throwing up the following error:

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="twocols"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]"}

the node tr[7] at the end of the xpath,becomes tr[6] as an additional element is getting added sometimes in the page.

The HTML data i want to extract is the date from the webpage as shown below.

```
<td class="">2019-08-06 16:16 BST</td>
```

How do i do this even if the realtive xpath keeps changing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one will be able to help if u not provide html code or link to your page.

Comment: agree with IPolnik. Is that the last row (either 6 or 7)? If the answer is yes, then try this xpath `(//*[@id="twocols"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr)[last()]/td[2]`

Comment: There are going to be some elements around that `td` you have provided that will be key in identifying an appropriate selector. Including the surrounding `html`, particularly the ancestors, would be very helpful.

Comment: this could be just syntax issue with single & double quotes. give it try with this, driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='twocols']/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]")

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you should know the column name for the value, you're trying to extract. So instead of hard-coding the column index you should be calculating the index of the "interesting" column instead. It can be done using [`count()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count) and [`preceding-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) combination:

For example given the following [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp):

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can match get:

- `Smith` as `//table/tr[2]/td[count(//table/tr/th[.='Lastname']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]`
- `Jackson` as `//table/tr[3]/td[count(//table/tr/th[.='Lastname']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]`
- `Jill` as `//table/tr[2]/td[count(//table/tr/th[.='Firstname']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]`
- etc.

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)